# Find the complex numbers $z$ such that $\left(\frac{\overline{z} +1}{z}\right )^6 = 1 $.

Tags: complex-numbers

> Solve 
>   $$\left(\frac{\overline{z} +1}{z}\right )^6 = 1.$$

I tried to write this in form $z= a+i b$ or $z=e^{i\varphi} $ but that doesn't seem to go anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

Hint. By taking the absolute value of both parts it follows that if $z=a+ib$ is a solution then
$$|\overline{z}+1|=|z|\Leftrightarrow (a+1)^2+(-b)^2=a^2+b^2\Leftrightarrow  2a+1=0\Leftrightarrow a=-\frac{1}{2}.$$
Now plug $z=-\frac{1}{2}+ib$ into the original equation and find $b$.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $\frac{\bar z + 1}{z} = \omega^k$ where $\omega = e^{i\pi/3}$. It follows that $\bar z + 1=\omega^kz$ and $z+1=\omega^{-k}\bar z$ which combined gives us $\omega^k = -1$ (just plug it in: $z+1=\omega^{-k}(\omega^kz-1)$). The equation becomes $\bar z + 1 = -z$, which gives us $\operatorname{Re}z = -\frac 12$. Plugging $z = -\frac 12 + bi$ into original equation gives us that $b$ can be any real.